# htaccess Redirect everything except subdomain and folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to redirect my whole domain www.example.de to www.domain.de/artikel.html except for 3 subdomains (and all whats in there) and 2 folders (and everything whats in there):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/subfolder2/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static1\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static2\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static3\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/artikel.html [R=301,L]
```

But it just redirects everything with www.example.de to www.domain.de/artikel.html but does not redirect anything for http://example.de.

Anyone a hint or solution for me??
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with this condition which causes redirections to occur only for subdomains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.de [NC]
```

replace it with :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (\.|^)example\.de [NC]
```

or you can completely remove it if your htaccess is attached to only one site (example.de)

your htaccess would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/subfolder2/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static1\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static2\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static3\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (\.|^)example\.de [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.de/artikel.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It helps with the www/non-www problem. But i still have a big problem: It only excludes the folders. but not the files within that folder. for example: i cannot open www.example.de/folder2/main.php

Comment: I partly fixed it: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/qm/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contao/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tl_files/(.*)?$ [NC]` now it works for www.example.de/folder2/main.php but not for www.example.de/folder1/subfolder2/test.html ??

Comment: it works :). But in my case the problem was, that the subfolder domains we routing back to an index.php in the root directory (bc it was contao cms). I also excluded the index.php and afterwards it worked perfect.